# Blank Output for AJAX Call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I am trying to read data from SQL server and display on webpage using [WebMethod] following this [tutorial](http://codepedia.info/jquery-ajax-json-example-asp-net-sql-database). I am using data and logic of my own.

Aim - To show count of incidents based on ProductName when clicked on the button.

**WebService.cs**

```
 public class Incidents
    {
        public string incidentProductName;
        public string incidentCount;
        public string incidentProductSearch;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Incidents> getCountOfIncidents(List<string> aData)
    {
        SqlDataReader dr;
        List<Incidents> incidentList = new List<Incidents>();
        string  conn = "Data Source = (LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = test; Integrated Security = True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "spGetIncidents";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductSearch", aData[0]);
                con.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string incidentproductname = dr["incidentProductName"].ToString();
                        string incidentcount = dr["incidentCount"].ToString();
                        string ProductSearch = dr["incidentProductSearch"].ToString();

                        incidentList.Add(new Incidents
                        {
                            incidentProductName = incidentproductname,
                            incidentCount = incidentcount,
                            incidentProductSearch = ProductSearch

                        });

                    }

                }
                return incidentList;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <script>
                $("#myButton").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var aData = [];
                    aData[0] = $("#ddlSelectProductName").val();
                    $("#contentHolder").empty();
                    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData: aData });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        //getCountOfIncidents is my webmethod   
                        url: "WebService.asmx/getCountOfIncidents",
                        data: jsonData,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        error: OnErrorCall
                    });

                    function OnSuccess(response) {
                        var items = response.d;
                        var fragment = "<ul>"
                        $.each(items, function (index, val) {

                            var incidentProductName = val.incidentProductName;
                            var incidentCount = val.incidentCount;
                            var incidentProductSearch = val.incidentProductSearch;
                            fragment += "<li> " + incidentProductName + " :: " + incidentCount + " - " + incidentProductSearch + "</li>";
                        });
                        $("#contentHolder").append(fragment);
                    }
                    function OnErrorCall(response) { console.log(error); }
                });
            </script>
            <select id="ddlSelectProductName">
                <option>ORACLE</option>
                <option>TERADATA</option>
            </select>
            <button id="myButton">Get List</button>
            <div id="contentHolder"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**SQL PROC**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetIncidents(
@ProductSearch varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
select [Incident Product Name],count([Incident Product Name]) as count from incidents where [Incident Product Name]=@ProductSearch group by [Incident Product Name];
END
```

The code executes but I see no output when I click the button **Get List**. I checked in Console as well, no error is there.

I am not sure how to debug or approach the problem.

EDIT -  My Webmethod has 0 hit counts when I tried using breakpoints

**Other details -**

- Using Visual Studio 2015.
- .Net 4.5 is being used.
- Browser Sync is unticked because it was throwing
  **XMLHttpRequest.WithCredentials for sync requests is deprecated**
- My Folder structure 
  [image]

Comment: Did you put a console.log in your onSuccess Method ? Does it logs something ? if you put a breakpoint on your webmethod does return  incidentList get hit when you debug ?

Comment: Yes I used `function OnSuccess(response) {
      console.log(response.d)
    }` before placing the actual function. Still no output.

Comment: @Massanu I just tried using breakpoint, It shows 0 hit counts.

Comment: Fix the ajax call first, be sure the webmethod receive the correct parameters, calls the Stored procedure and return the incidentList before focusing on your clientSide.

Comment: @Massanu AJAX looks fine. Anything you can pin point ?

Answer (score 1):

2 things to look at that I can see:

1. Your AJAX looks fine but I'd add a `cache: false` to the options list in the call.  You could have not returned any data and that got cached so it's not hitting your webmethod anymore.
2. Since we don't know what version of .Net you're using and I've seen issues in web site projects (vs web application projects) you could be missing some needed items in your web.config to enable ajax calls.  I have these in a .Net 3.5 app

---

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It has more to do with AJAX toolkit but the projects these were in didn't work without it being present.